# Prove that $A \setminus (B \setminus A) = A$ for arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My reasoning so far is that if $x \in A \setminus (B \setminus A)$ then $x \in A$ and $x  \notin (B \setminus A)$ which is equivalent to $x \in A$ and ($x \notin B$ or $x \in A$), but I'm not sure how to go from here.

Comment: Your "then $x\in A$ and ..." already showed one direction: $A\setminus(B\setminus A) \subseteq A$. Next, you need to also show if $x\in A$ then $x\in A\setminus(B\setminus A)$.

Comment: $$ A \cap [(B\cap A^c)]^c = A\cap (A \cup B^c) = A \cup (A\cap B^c)$$ As $A\cap B^c \subset A$, we have $A\cup (A\cap B^c) = A$, as desired.

Comment: $[x\in A \wedge (x\notin B \vee x \in A)] = x\in A$ is the [absorption law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that $A = A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$ it suffices to prove that $A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A) \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$.

The first case is trivial, $A\;\backslash\;C$ will always be a subset of $A$ for any $C$, since it's defined by taking all of $A$ and removing elements.

In order to prove that $A \subseteq A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$ we need to show that if $x \in A$ then $x \in A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$.

Well, if $x \in A$, then $x \notin B\;\backslash\;A$, since it's a part of the set being removed from $B$. Then since $x \in A$ and $x \notin B\;\backslash\;A$ we have that $x \in A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$, since it is a part of the original set, but not the part being removed.

Thus $A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A) \subseteq A$ and $A \subseteq A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$, and consequently $A = A\;\backslash\;(B\;\backslash\;A)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you start with a set (here, $A$) and remove any set (here, $B - A$) you cannot gain new elements. You can only lose elements. So, to ensure that the resulting set after this removal is still $A$, it suffices to ask: Did you lose anything in $A$?

Answer: No, nothing in $A$ was lost. The reason for this is that everything removed explicitly excluded $A$.

And that does it: All of $A$ is preserved and the desired equality holds.